# How to return the value from function

Tags: vb6, return-value

How to return the value from function

Code

```
Private Function LeaveCheck(empid As String)
    Dim rdoRs1 As rdoResultset
    Dim desc As String
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "Select name from table1 wher empcode = '" & empid & "'"
    Set rdoRs1 = Rdoconn.OpenResultset(sSQL, rdOpenStatic)
    If rdoRs1.RowCount > 0 Then
    desc = rdors1!name        
    return desc 'Showing error in this line    
    End If
    rdoRs1.Close
End Function
```

How to return the value from the above code.

Need Vb6 code Help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify your return type.

```
Private Function LeaveCheck(empid As String) As String ' Notice the As String
    Dim rdoRs1 As rdoResultset  
    Dim desc As String  
    Dim sSQL As String  
    sSQL = "Select name from table1 wher empcode = '" & empid & "'"  
    Set rdoRs1 = Rdoconn.OpenResultset(sSQL, rdOpenStatic)  
    If rdoRs1.RowCount > 0 Then  
        desc = rdors1!name          
    End If  
    rdoRs1.Close  

    LeaveCheck = desc ' This will be blank or populated
End Function
```

Here is a [link](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-subroutines-and-functions-vb) that is a good read for understanding Functions in VB6

**EDIT**

After reading your comment, I would create a class to store your values.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Dim name As String
    Dim dept As String
    Dim country As String
End Class
```

Then, you can instantiate a new instance of this class inside of your code:

```
Private Function LeaveCheck(empid As String) As MyClass
    Dim myClass As New MyClass
    Dim rdoRs1 As rdoResultset
    Dim sSQL As String   
    sSQL = "Select name, dept, country from table1 wher empcode = '" & empid & "'"   
    Set rdoRs1 = Rdoconn.OpenResultset(sSQL, rdOpenStatic)   
    If rdoRs1.RowCount > 0 Then   
        myClass.name = rdors1!name           
        myClass.dept = rdors1!dept
        myClass.country = rdors1!country
    End If   
    rdoRs1.Close   

    LeaveCheck = myClass
End Function
```

Comment: If i want to send multiple values means, how do modify my code, for example name, dept, country i want to return, for that what i have to modify my code....

Comment: @Gopal: If you want to return the `RecordSet`, change the return type to `rdoResultSet`.  However, you are closing the `RecordSet` before you are leaving the function and this may cause issues later on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the value to the function name and the return type:

```
Private Function LeaveCheck(empid As String) As String
    Dim rdoRs1 As rdoResultset
    Dim desc As String
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "Select name from table1 wher empcode = '" & empid & "'"
    Set rdoRs1 = Rdoconn.OpenResultset(sSQL, rdOpenStatic)
    If rdoRs1.RowCount > 0 Then
      desc = rdors1!name        
    End If
    rdoRs1.Close

    LeaveCheck = desc

End Function
```

See [this document](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-subroutines-and-functions-vb) for more information.

Comment: If i want to send multiple values means,  for example name, dept, country i want to return, for that what i have to modify my code....

Comment: @Gopal - Why not return the whole result set? Or create an object to hold these values and return that.

Comment: Ok i will return the result set, from other end how can i use that record set.  For example, i am return the resultset rdo then in the formload how i can use that rdo result, Can you please help me....

Comment: RDO is not ADO, but a supplement to DAO that was a stopgap for VB5 before VB6 came along with good ADO support.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function returnArray() As Variant
   RTA[ab]=0
   if a=b then RTA[ab]=1

   RTA[xy]=0
   if a=b then RTA[xy]=1

   returnArray=RTA
end function
```